# Помогите пожалуйста оптимизировать код c++

Tags: c++, массивы, шахматы

Ходы ферзя

На шахматной доске стоит ферзь. Отметьте положение ферзя на доске и все клетки, которые бьёт ферзь. Клетку, где стоит ферзь, отметьте буквой «Q», клетки, которые бьёт ферзь, отметьте символами «*», остальные клетки заполните точками.

Входные данные

В двух строках входного файла заданы два числа — координаты нахождения ферзя. Числа во входном файле натуральные, не превосходящие 8
8
по значению.

Выходные данные

Выведите на экран изображение доски так, как это показано в примере. Обратите внимание, что символы в одной строке разделены пробелом.

Пример:

Входные данные
4 2

Выходные данные

```
 . * . * . . . . 
 * * * . . . . . 
 * Q * * * * * * 
 * * * . . . . . 
 . * . * . . . . 
 . * . . * . . . 
 . * . . . * . .
```

Не принимают задачу, тк "Программа использовала слишком много памяти и была прервана". При тестировании кода ошибок не было

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{   short cki, ckj, i, j, p = 2, b, k;
    cin >> cki >> ckj;
    cki += 1;
    ckj += 1;
    vector <vector <int>> board(12, vector <int> (12, 0));
    for (i = 2; i < 10; i = i + 1){
        for (j = 2; j < 10; j = j + 1){
            if (i == cki && j == ckj){
                    if (cki >= ckj){
                        for (k = cki - ckj + 2; k < 10; k = k + 1){
                            board[k][p] = 2;
                            p = p + 1;}
                        if (ckj == 2 || ckj == 3 || ckj == 8 || ckj == 9){
                            p = ckj - 1;
                            b = cki + 1;}
                        else if (ckj == 4 || ckj == 7){
                            p = ckj - 2;
                            b = cki + 2;}
                        else if (ckj == 5 || ckj == 6){
                            p = ckj - 3;
                            b = cki + 3;}
                        for (k = b; k > 1; k = k - 1){
                            board[k][p] = 2;
                            p = p + 1;}
                    }else{
                        p = ckj - cki + 2;
                        for (k = 2; k < 10; k = k + 1){
                            board[k][p] = 2;
                            p = p + 1;
                        }if (cki == 2 || cki == 3 || cki == 7 || cki == 8){
                            p = ckj + 1;
                            b = cki - 1;}
                        else if (cki == 4 || cki == 6){
                            p = ckj + 2;
                            b = cki - 2;}
                        else if (cki == 5){
                            p = ckj + 3;
                            b = cki - 3;}
                        for (k = b; k < 10; k = k + 1){
                            board[k][p] = 2;
                            p = p - 1;;}
                    }for (k = 2; k < 10; k = k + 1){
                        board[k][ckj] = 2;
                        board[cki][k] = 2;}}}
    }for (i = 2; i < 10; i = i + 1){
        for (j = 2; j < 10; j = j + 1){
            if (i == cki && j == ckj) cout << "Q" << " ";
            else if (board[i][j] == 2) cout << "*" << " ";
            else if (board[i][j] == 0) cout << "." << " ";}
        cout << endl;}}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вообще-то у вас на картинке 7 строк, а не 8...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зачем просто, если можно сложно? :)

Выводить надо все клетки, так что проще всего - двойной цикл + проверка условия "бития":

```
int main()
{
    int qi, qj;
    cin >> qi >> qj;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 8; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j <= 8; ++j)
            cout <<
                ((i == qi && j ==qj) ? 'Q' :   // Это координаты ферзя?
                (i == qi                       // Строка
                 || j ==qj                     // или столбец
                 || abs(i-qi)==abs(j-qj))      // или диагональ?
                            ? '*' : '.');
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, очень помогли. Только вот что значат "?" и ":" в cout?

Comment: [Тернарный оператор](https://purecodecpp.com/archives/554)

Comment: Почему-то не сразу понял, что последнее условие в втором тернарном операторе - это условия диагоналей ... Можно было бы и прокомментировать для наглядности

Answer (score 2):

Вот смотрите: для решения не нужно никакие структуры данных - списки, массивы, векторы... Просто в двойном цикле выводите символы.

А для определения символа выполняете проверку - совпадают обе координаты с заданными координатами ферзя - выводите Q, совпадает одна координата, или модули разностей координат равны - выводите звёздочку, иначе - точку